# Can I identify by row the first and last observation

Tags: r

would like to identify the number of firms that start and end each month. The goal is to say by column how much firms start and end.

My data looks like this, with many more rows and columns.

```
  Firm   Return_1990_01  Return_1990_02 Return_1990_03 Return_1990_04 Return_1990_05 
#1 fg23         NaN             NaN             1.54          2.34        .641      
#2 sdf1         1.35            NaN             3.53          NaN         .231     
#3 sdf1         1.12            2.44            1.51          1.64         NaN
```

One challenge is that a firm can have NaNs in between. For example, Row 2 the firm begins 1990_01 and ends 1990_05 despite NaNs in between.

I tried the following code

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  gather(month, value, -Firm) %>% 
  filter(!is.nan(value)) %>% 
  arrange(Firm, month) %>% 
  group_by(Firm) %>% 
  summarise(start = first(month), end = last(month))
```

But get the following error message

```
Error in arrange_impl(.data, dots) : 
  data frame column with incompatible number of rows (465), expecting : 59378
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
apply(df[,-1], 1, function(x) range(which(!is.nan(x))))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    3    1    1
# [2,]    5    5    4
```

If you want to add names to rows and columns then we can extend this as:

```
apply(df[,-1], 1, function(x) range(which(!is.nan(x)))) %>%
  t %>%
  `colnames<-`(c('First','Last')) %>%
  `row.names<-`(df[,1])
#      First Last
# fg23     3    5
# sdf1     1    5
# sdf1     1    4
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to represent this with column names using `tidyverse`.  We `gather` the data into long format and select only first and last value for each row. Create a new column (`temp`) which holds `"Start"` and `"End"` for each group and `spread` it to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  gather(key, value, -Firm, -row, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  slice(c(1L, n())) %>%
  mutate(temp = c("Start", "End")) %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  spread(temp, key) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-row) %>%
  select(Firm, Start, End)

#  Firm  Start          End           
#  <fct> <chr>          <chr>         
#1 fg23  Return_1990_03 Return_1990_05
#2 sdf1  Return_1990_01 Return_1990_05
#3 sdf1  Return_1990_01 Return_1990_04
```

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyverse`, we can do this without any reshaping with `pmap`.  Find the `names` of the  elements that are not NaN with `which`, get the `first` and `last` column names

```
library(tidyverse)
df  %>% 
   transmute(Firm, start_end = pmap(.[-1], ~ 
       which(!is.nan(c(...))) %>%
       names %>%
       range %>%
       {tibble(start = first(.), end = last(.))})) %>%
   unnest
#  Firm          start            end
#1 fg23 Return_1990_03 Return_1990_05
#2 sdf1 Return_1990_01 Return_1990_05
#3 sdf1 Return_1990_01 Return_1990_04
```

---

In `base R`, we can also do this in a vectorized way with `max.col`

```
m1 <- !is.na(df[-1])
start <- colnames(m1)[max.col(m1, "first")]
end <- colnames(m1)[max.col(m1, "last")]
cbind(df1['Firm'], start, end)
#  Firm          start            end
#1 fg23 Return_1990_03 Return_1990_05
#2 sdf1 Return_1990_01 Return_1990_05
#3 sdf1 Return_1990_01 Return_1990_04
```